# Set path to Android Studio in Windows

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to configure the path to Android Studio on my Windows.
I'v tried these commands:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
```

and

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio
```

[but second didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldq5F.png)

I can't change path because it gets cut in cmd.
I've tried to uninstall and re-install flutter SDK, but it didn't fix the flutter doctor errors.
I understood that with ANDROID_HOME already set it was really foolish to implement these commands...

Is this path to android studio correct?
I've zero skills in programming, so I don't even know the basics

Answer (score 0):

run in ***cmd*** :

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```